# Getting a universally correct date in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, date, time, command

I have a script which is amending a UNIX server time, changing it from its current correct time it is set to, to another time. Once i've changed it, id like to then set it back to the current time in UTC that is correct, synchronizing it with the world again.

Is there a command that can do this? All I know and see are the usual date retrieval commands, but nothing to retrieve a date that is known globally to be 'correct'.

Comment: I suggest recording both the current time on the server and the current time from an outside source, taking the difference and storing both the current time on the server and the difference, then changing the time on the server however you like, then get the new value from the outside source, take the difference that you found before, and apply that to the new outside time and use the result to update the time on the server.

Comment: Google "NTP". It already takes care of all the details necessary for accurately synchronizing your clock to an external clock.

Comment: I have tried to use NTP but it doesn't seem to set the server time. I have a ntpd server running by checking with `service ntpd status`, but when i run the command `ntpdate -s europe.pool.ntp.org` it doesnt change the server time.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. Don't look for an alternate solution, look for a solution to the problem you're having with NTP, which is the right solution. Consider that NTP doesn't change the time if it is too farr off. Check `man ntp` for arguments to force this: `-g -x -q`.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to resolve my NTP setup issues, and was unable to do so after following tutorials. I have opted to using the below line to extract the global time.

```
date -s $(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 google.com 2>&1 | grep Date: | cut -d' ' -f5-8)Z
```